# artillery.io xhr poll error

Tags: socket.io, load-testing

I am unable to connect using artillery.io with setting engine = socketio, please find my configuration json below

`socket error {"type":"Transport error", "description":400}`

`"scenarios": [
    {
      "name": "my test",
      "engine": "socketio",
      "flow": [
        {
          "emit": {
            "channel": "command",
            "namespace": "command"
          }
        },
        {
          "think": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
"scenarios": [
    {
      "name": "my test",
      "engine": "socketio",
      "flow": [
        {
          "emit": {
            "channel": "command"
            "data": "hello"
            "namespace": "/command"
          }
        },
        {
          "think": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Please try using above command